# adding NaoQI to the PYTHONPATH

Tags: ros, naoqi, nao, nao-robot, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I loaded the nao_robot and nao_common stacks and am trying to operate the driver, however, i am a newbie to ROS, and am unsure of how to add Aldebaran's NaoQI API to the PYTHONPATH.  Is this done in the setup.sh file, or by physically moving the directory.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Brendan Gates
Undergraduate Research Assistant - Umaine B.E.A.R. Lab

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28814/adding-naoqi-to-the-pythonpath/) by [univ_maine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1868/univ_maine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [univ_maine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1868/univ_maine/) on 2012-03-16**:
Thanks for the Response Stefan!  It didn't quite work though, i got the following error. No handlers could be found for logger "rosout"
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1331912435.002598] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.  Any ideas what else to try?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-16**:
If you use NaoQI version 1.12, please refer to this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/28902/adding-naoqi-api-to-pythonpath-v112?answer=29878#post-id-29878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add the `lib` subdirectory of Aldebaran's SDK to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable by executing

```
export PYTHONPATH=/your/path/to/naoqi-sdk-1.10.52-linux/lib:${PYTHONPATH}
```

before you launch nodes from `nao_robot`. If you do not want to type this line every time, you can add this line to your `~/.profile` file, which is executed automatically whenever you start a new shell.

Afterwards, you can launch the nao driver nodes with

```
NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch
```

(replace 127.0.0.1 by the IP of your robot).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Osswald](https://answers.ros.org/users/1042/stefan-osswald/) with karma: 281 on 2012-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1